# NordVPN on Linux Mint

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, vpn, openvpn, nordvpn

This is an unfortunately specific question, I'd much rather ask something more generic, but I'm just stumped. I install the latest Linux Mint, then I go to the NordVPN site and follow the guide to install NordVPN there, and ... nothing. I follow the companies own guide. https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/Linux/1325531132/Installing-and-using-NordVPN-on-Debian-Ubuntu-Raspberry-Pi-Elementary-OS-and-Linux-Mint.htm

```
sh <(curl -sSf https://downloads.nordcdn.com/apps/linux/install.sh)
nordvpn login
nordvpn connect
```

It accepts my login credentials and then says "Close this window to return to the app?" so I do that and go back to the console, then it just says "You are not logged into NordVPN" if I try to run any command.

Can someone with Ubuntu/Debian/LinuxMint related experience with NordVPN point out what I'm missing or doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this in case someone misses it. I got stuck on this on Ubunu:

```
nordvpn login --callback nordvpn://login?action=login&exchange_token=XXXXX&status=done
```

To fix it, I had to add the link in quotes:

```
nordvpn login --callback "nordvpn://login?action=login&exchange_token=XXXXX&status=done"
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't really tell what went wrong for you because I didn't use that script, but I can recount how I managed to set things up a few weeks ago (still on Mint 19, though).

I got a bit confused because that guide has a link "Download the NordVPN Linux client" that leads to a page where you get a `.deb` file instead of the shell script, but that worked for me. So:

1. `curl -O https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian/pool/main/nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb`
2. `sudo apt install ./nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb`
3. `sudo apt update`
4. `sudo apt install nordvpn`
5. re-login or run `su - $USER` (the previous step prints a message that this is necessary)
6. `nordvpn login`
7. a login page opens in the browser, log in there
8. the "Return to the app" link there didn't work for me, so I copied the URL
9. `nordvpn login --callback <copied_URL>`

After that `nordvpn connect <country>` worked.

Comment: Thanks so much for looking at this. It's just incredibly broken. You'd think these people would make sure it works, but nope, and I see this with so many things on Linux, always broken and the companies never bother to fix it.

Comment: boss@loft:~$ nordvpn login
Continue in the browser: https://zwyr157wwiu6eior.com/v1/users/oauth/login-redirect?attempt=e94f330f-a6a1-4454-8cb1-ce270f1638f5
boss@loft:~$ nordvpn account
You are not logged in.
boss@loft:~$ nordvpn login --callback nordvpn://login?action=login&exchange_token=ZWJlODhmOTM5NWRjNjZlZTM4NjMzMmQ1MTcyYWQ5MTQwYTYxMTM5NDlmYzQ3Y2I5NzNjZmVmNTg5NjhjYmI0OA%3D%3D&status=done
[1] 119406
[2] 119407
Exchange token not provided.

Comment: [1]-  Exit 1                  nordvpn login --callback nordvpn://login?action=login
[2]+  Done                    exchange_token=ZWJlODhmOTM5NWRjNjZlZTM4NjMzMmQ1MTcyYWQ5MTQwYTYxMTM5NDlmYzQ3Y2I5NzNjZmVmNTg5NjhjYmI0OA%3D%3D

Comment: The above is what I get when I copy the URK from the page and try to run it as you said. It's just completely broken, and it's very disappointing. 

Comment: The URL contains `&` characters that you haven't escaped on the command line, that's not really a problem of the tool. Does it work when you put the URL in quotes in step 9?

Comment: In the end I got it working by using the `--legacy` flag (which is not in any way referenced in the NordVPN tutoirial ...). Thanks very much for your help on this Don.